# How to set mongod.conf bind_ip with multiple ip address

Tags: mongodb, virtual-machine, remote-access

I am a newbie for setting up the server environment and mongoDB. This may sounds something really simple, however, I really need your help on it.

I am trying to connect to my virtual machine which runs the mongodb instance from the local machine, which I believe should be similar to the production environment when I run it on a separate remote server.

The environment is as following:

- Private IP for virtual machine: *192.168.184.155*
- Public IP for both local machine and virtual machine: *96.88.169.145*

I changed the **bind_ip** in **/etc/mongod.conf file** from

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.184.155,96.88.169.145
```

After I restarted the mongod service, neither the virtual machine nor the local machine can access mongodb through mongodb command and giving me the following error.

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
connecting to: test
2015-03-17T16:02:22.705-0400 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-03-17T16:02:22.707-0400 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

However, if I change the

```
bind_ip = 192.168.184.155
```

and restart the service, it works and I can access using mongo from my local machine. It seems just not work with multiple ip addresses. I tried to do look up in the mongodb document, however, they does mention that bind_ip takes a comma separated list, which really confused me.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What if you use bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.184.155? To me 96.88.169.145 is not a valid IP on your VM

Comment: @anhlc It's the same result. Once I have added more than one ip address, none of them works. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you get the parsed command line options from the log when you boot mongod? It really should work, so I wonder if there's some weird VM networking obstacle here?

Comment: Hi @wdberkeley, thank you so much for bring it up! I checked the log file and find out the problem! It seems I happened to add a space before the next ip address, which crash the whole thing.

Comment: I agree with wdberkeley, it's _always_ worth checking the log file, to see if there are any clues there about what is going wrong.

Comment: I would recommend to set `bindIpAll: true` Using `bindIp` with an IP address is useful when you have a machine with several network interfaces, otherwise it does not make much sense in my opinion. Exception is `bindIp: localhost` when you like to prevent any external connection, typically used while maintenance work.

Comment: A public IP is typically achieved by your router using [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), i.e. your local computer does not know this address and thus it does not make any sense to bind such an IP.

Answer (score 62):

Wrap the comma-separated-Ips with brackets works in mongo 3.2.7 for me:

```
bindIp = [127.0.0.1, 192.168.184.155, 96.88.169.145]
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted but this seems to be norm now

Comment: there shouldn't be the brackets or spaces after the commas anymore. it's also bind_ip instead of bindIp. this is for ubuntu might be different for other systems...

Comment: Both joe-cheng's and @puneet-goyal's solutions work. With spaces brackets are needed, without spaces just a comma-separated list works.

Comment: In my case it didn't work 3.6 here. It added bracked as part of the IP.

Comment: bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 10.8.0.1   # works for centos 7.4, mongo 3.6

Comment: I get: Jun 02 19:04:31 mongod[23698]: Scalar option 'net.bindIp' must be a single value
Jun 02 19:04:31 mongod[23698]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information

Comment: I am using latest version. The above solution did not work for me

Comment: none of these work on mongodb 6

Answer (score 25):

With the following version of MongoDB:
MongoDB shell version v3.6.10

**Reproducing Problem:**
When [127.0.0.1,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] is used we get the following error.
    Scalar option 'net.bindIp' must be a single value
    try 'mongod --help' for more information

**Analysis**
This is because, according to MongoDB Documentation: `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIP`

net.bindIP is of type "**string**".

**Solution for binding multiple IP Addresses**

```
bindIp: "127.0.0.1,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Note: No spaces after commas

Comment: it worked for mongo 4.4.8 version

Comment: doesnt work for mongo 6.0

Comment: still work for mongo 6.0

Comment: Not works for MongoDB 7.0 (demands ; - semicolon divider)

Answer (score 17):

You can do that by:

```
bindIp: [172.31.60.184,127.0.0.1]
```

Remember to not put a space after the comma.

Comment: What version of MongoDb are you using? I'm trying with 2.6 and this does not seem to work (list with comma, no space) nor the version with brackets.

Comment: This does not work on `db version v3.2.12
git version: ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14 Ubuntu 16.04`.  Using the brackets in answer below works

Comment: for some reason this '[172.31.60.184,127.0.0.1]' does not work in version 3.6.8. what worked for me was modifying /etc/mongodb.conf and inserting:
binding_ip = 172.31.60.184,localhost
that will bind to the first ip sepecified and to the localhost.

Answer (score 7):

The default /etc/mongod.conf file has this entry for network interfaces:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

This corresponds to the `--bind-ip arg` parameter on the command line. Notice the dash notation converted to camel case. To expose the database running in a VM to the host, it's simplest to bind the database to all interfaces for testing purposes. This will cover situations where the VM is using a NAT interface or bridged interface. The command line parameter is `--bind_ip_all` which does not have a parameter, it's existence corresponds to the `bindIPAll: true` parameter in the configuration file. Therefore, the configuration file should be changed to:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
```

Notice the `bindIp` parameter is removed.

It should also be noted that it is possible to add parameters to the command line that override parameters in the config file. Normally, mongod is run with the `--config /etc/mongod.conf` parameter. It's easier to change the config file instead of hunting down the script what runs it as a daemon and getting `systemd` to reload and use it.

For details on the YAML-ness of the config file vs. parameters on the command line, see the documentation currently at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

If you are running mongod on a VM using NAT, the default port `27017` will not be exposed to the host. It will be necessary to map a port on the host to this port in the guest VM. That's beyond the scope of this answer, but a little research will provide a method used for the VM software you are using (VirtualBox, VMware, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

In my case, with mongoDB 4.4.6 following solution worked -

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1;<private_host_ip>
```

After making changes, restart mongoDB with following command -

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

To Check mongoDB status, run -

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Comment: This works with the config. but I am not able to run the mongo shell it is throwing error `connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17`

Comment: @KartikGarasia - Please send detailed error log, or may be screenshot of your mongo conf file.

Comment: This works for MongoDB shell version v4.0.28

Comment: Doesn't appear to work with MongoDB shell version v4.4.9

Answer (score 6):

MongoDB 6.0.1

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1;192.168.1.0
```

After change just restart mongodb server:

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

Comment: Didn't work for me using 6.0.0

Comment: as per documentation: "enter a list of comma-separated values". so replace semi-colon. (@Dylee try this way)

Answer (score 4):

In my case the solution was to put the comma separated IP and without any spaces.

```
bind_ip=192.168.2.29,127.0.0.1
#port = 27017
```

That way worked:

```
2018-10-02T07:49:27.952+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "192.168.2.29,127.0.0.1", unixDomainSocket: { pathPrefix: "/run/mongodb" } }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" } } 2018-10-02T07:49:27.954+0000 I -    [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
```

Mongo 3.6.3 here.

mongod --version
db version v3.6.3
git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for @wdberkeley and @anhlc brought up the clue.

I looked at the log file under /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log. It shows the failing reason for the problem.

```
2015-03-17T16:08:17.274-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1, 192.168.184.155" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2015-03-17T16:08:17.332-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] getaddrinfo(" 192.168.184.155") failed: Name or service not known
```

So the mongo.conf file is sensitive to space, which I happened to add and should have noticed. Also just as @anhlc pointed out, 96.88.169.145 is not a valid IP address for VM. So that one also contribute to the error.

Great thanks for both of your help! Hope this may help if someone happened to run into the same problem.

Comment: You mean we should write something like this: `bind_ip=127.0.0.1 192.168.184.155 96.88.169.145` i.e. space separated instead of comma separated?

Answer (score 3):

I successfully added a second ip on my version 3.2 service using a comma, no spaces and an FQDN

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: localhost,dev-2.office.sampleorg.com
```

Answer (score 3):

I am running 3.6 on SUSE 12.x and had an issues using comma separated IP lists. I fixed the issue by
        bindIp: 0.0.0.0

Comment: Thanks i was having same problem none of the above and below solution worked but yours +1

Comment: 0.0.0.0 will work because you aren't binding to any server which essentially binds it to your Public IP and can potentially expose your database to the public. Will work, but bad idea.

Comment: Don't think so. 0.0.0.0  is a non-routable meta-address. In the context of servers, 0.0.0.0 means "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine".

Comment: I still think it is a bit hacky. It is basically allowing any IP address that gains access to the local server. For 3.6, the safest way would be to `bindIp: 127.0.0.1, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and under that `bindIpAll: true` <-- default value is false.

Comment: Not a great idea, it will expose your database.

Comment: Not sure, how? can you give me an example?

Comment: Wow... don't do this ! It will let any IP address to access your DB.

Answer (score 2):

In Mongo 3.*,

use a bracket such as

```
net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp : [127.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The case in **mongodb version 3.6** on my Ubuntu16.04 LTS is that you do not need to put the IP addresses in the square brackets "[]". **Delete the space after the comma** solve the failed connection problem in the mongod log (/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log)

```
NETWORK  [initandlisten] getaddrinfo(" xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") failed: Name or service not known
```

After modify the `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` to `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` **(notice no comma between IPs)**, the host IP is listening as below:

```
xxx@xxxx:/var/log/mongodb$ sudo netstat -plnt |egrep mongod
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30747/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30747/mongod
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 -> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10

For me the following works:

#### bind_ip = [127.0.0.1;X.X.X.X]

Notice I have a `;` not `,`

Comment: Ubuntu 14 with mongo 2.6 also works like this. Thanks finezza

Answer (score 1):

The bindIp rule with comma separated IP addresses is only meant for known ethernet interfaces, or for the 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 rules. You can only use the ip addresses of your system's Network Interface Cards. If this list contains an unknown IP address, i.e. an IP of another system, your MongoDb instance will not restart and hence you're not able to connect. To check if your MongoDb instance is running, run the following:

```
$ sudo systemctl status mongod
```

If you would like to make your MongoDb instance available to other systems on your network, you'll want to bind the local IP associated with the private network. To determine network interface configuration easily, just run an ifconfig from the command line:

```
$ ifconfig
```

This will list all available IP addresses that you can use in the bindIp rule. Most certainly, the IP address 96.88.169.145 that you use is not a valid IP address or unknown by your system.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon-linux2 | Cent OS | MongoDB shell version: 3.0.15

This is how it needs to be done in the latest config

```
#network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,127.0.0.1]  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Error: Scalar option 'net.bindIp' must be a single value

Answer (score 1):

For `4.4.6`, so - lets assume for series 4.x (perhaps for some of series 3.x)

The correct syntax is:

- `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<private_host_ip>,<public_host_ip>`

For each new IP just use `,` and without any spaces

For LAN access must be used the `private_host_ip`, you can use `ipconfig` or `ip a` for *Windows* and *Linux* respectively to know the ip value.
Of course for public WAN access must be used `<public_host_ip>`, it about your ISP

**Warning** both ips - `private_host_ip` and `<public_host_ip>` - are the locations where your **MongoDB** *server* is running, not the remote clients. Therefore exists the wrong assumption to add each new ip where each one represents the *remote **client** IP address* (other different than the ***server** IP address* - LAN and/or WAN), it is **not** correct.

**Note** To avoid problems is better for both use static ips, the private through your router and the second through your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Here I resolve this issue using bellow code. my mongod version 4.4.21.

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, <your_server_ip>
  bindIpAll: true
```

After Changes restart the mongod service

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

To verify the connection write bellow code in your local system terminal

```
nc -zv <your_server_ip> 27017
```

Output :

```
Connection to <your_server_ip> port 27017 [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB server version: 3.6.8 plain comma separated list worked for me. With or without spaces after comma.

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.104
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.104
```

However, adding enclosing in `[]` fails with following error in MongoDB log

```
bind_ip = [127.0.0.1,192.168.0.104]
getaddrinfo("[127.0.0.1") failed: Name or service not known

bind_ip = [127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.104]
getaddrinfo("[127.0.0.1") failed: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my mongo **v4.2.15**:

`vi /etc/mongod.conf`

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1;X.X.X.X;Y.Y.Y.Y
```

`sudo systemctl restart mongod`

Answer (score 0):

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1;53.254.16.5
```

This for MongoDB 4.4, CentOS 7

Answer (score -11):

If all you want to do is connect to this machine over the network you do **NOT** need to modify the `bind_ip` value.

In your case you need to follow the following steps.

1. Setup the remote machine to block all connections to port 27017
2. Enable remote machine to only accept connections from your local machine
3. Setup credentials with MongoDB
4. Connect with client using credentials.

If you are not sure how to do any of this steps. Check out a blog post that I wrote that goes more in details how to do this.

## [Blog Post](http://codewithintent.com/how-to-setup-access-to-mongodb-in-production-with-local-clients-robomongo-humongous-io/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: What part? He wants to access a machine from a public location simple networking.

Comment: Make sure that if you downvote this answer you post why?
 https://youtu.be/Jsb-9iM_tiw

Comment: i downvoted this answer because its wrong. An example why, consider a private network. Network security prevents unauthorized access to the mongo cluster. But the clients need to be bound to the private interface for it work. but, you in circumstance you may need to bind localhost as well for statistics, maintenance etc. bind all would be dangerous, even with credentials. my webservers connect to my mongo cluster over private network interface (local subnet) much safer than public internet.

Comment: Your answer and blog post are not relevant to the OP's question - which was about issues with configuring bind_ip on a virtual machine.