# Mongodb error connect ETIMEDOUT on AWS EC2 windows

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have created one EC2 instance of Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have installed MongoDB on that server.

I setup an inbound rule to allow port 27017 to connect to MongoDb from my local machine.

Now I am trying to connect using MongoDB GUI tool (MongoBooster) and its giving following error.

```
{
"message" : "connect ETIMEDOUT X.X.X.X:27017",
"name" : "MongoError",
"stack" : "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT X.X.X.X:2701" +
          "at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:949:11" +
          "at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:972:20" +
          "at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)"
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you modified the `bind_ip` setting as described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884021/mongodb-bind-ip-wont-work-unless-set-to-0-0-0-0

Comment: @MarkB, The solution you provided was for linux system. How can I do that for windows server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding config file (mongodb.conf), You need to create one file with .conf extension. And add below configuration in this file:

```
dbpath = c:\data\db
port = 27017
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
logpath = c:\data\logs\mongoconf.log
```

And Start Command prompt as Administrator. And change directory to your mongo bin directory **C:\mongodb\bin** and run below command

```
mongod -config c:\mongodb\config\mongodb.conf
```

**And please check your firewall is off or you can set appropriate settings in Firewall also.**

Comment: Thank you very much, I have done above settings and also I needed to turn off the firewall to connect it over internet. And it just worked. Can we do it by doing firewall on?

Comment: Yes, You can do it with firewall on. You just need to set inbound rules in Firewall Advance Settings for predefined rule "World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In)" and also set rules for Port 27017.