# Mongo service start or restart always fail

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed mongodb then I've created a mongo service:

```
 [Unit]
    Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    User=mongodb
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But When I launch the service and then I check the status, I get always this error:

```
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-04-24 13:08:55 UTC; 6min ago
  Process: 1094 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
 Main PID: 1094 (code=exited, status=48)

Apr 24 13:08:54 ip-172-31-37-163 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Apr 24 13:08:55 ip-172-31-37-163 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a
Apr 24 13:08:55 ip-172-31-37-163 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 24 13:08:55 ip-172-31-37-163 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem was in config file and changing

> bindIp: 127.0.0.1, X.X.X.X

to

> bindIp: [127.0.0.1, X.X.X.X]

Solved my issue

Comment: Similar issue appears here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884021/mongodb-bind-ip-wont-work-unless-set-to-0-0-0-0 .

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the owner permissions

> chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
>
> chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB 3.6 the brackets proposed by @Chlebta did not work for me, returning the error:

> mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT

My mistake was separating the IP addresses with commas and spaces. There has to be only commas between the addresses:

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1,X.X.X.X,Y.Y.Y.Y
```

Comment: There is no capital 'P' to bindIp. Even with that correction I'm still stuck.

Comment: True. Misspelling fixed, thanks. Also, look for tabs in the file. The conf file only works with spaces.

Comment: I'll check that. I think the issue is that those IP need to be on the same network and I'm trying to allow an external IP access to the database.

Comment: Ok. It should be possible. Use the IP address of the machine where you are editing the conf file, not the addresses of the external machines. I have 3 servers in Digital Ocean that communicate between them through VPN, so I used the private IP.

Comment: Hmm that's what I'm doing already. But writing the IP of the machine I'm editing the conf file on is pretty much the same as writing 127.0.0.1, right?  Here is my full problem. I have a machine with an Express/Nodejs server and a MongoDB/Mongod daemon installed on it. If I write `BindIp : www.myAddress.com` in the conf file the server talks to the data base just fine.
What I want to be able to do is browse my database with Mongo Compass from another computer without the `bindAllIp : true` parameter.

Comment: It is not the same as writing 127.0.0.1. BindIp is the address through which other servers will see your MongoDB server. In your case, if your Express server is on the same machine as your MongoDB, leave BindIp with 127.0.0.1 and make Express connect to that. If Express and MongoDB are in separate machines, put in BindIp the address of the MongoDB server. I browse my db remotely with Robo 3T. It first connects to the server via ssh and then connects to MongoDB asking for localhost. It does not need anything from BindIp. I don't know if Mongo Compass can do that.

Comment: Hmm I see. I don't need Compass specifically, Robo3T seems good enough. How does Robo3T access the database through the server? I mean, what did you configure on the server for it to work?

Comment: Fill the tabs you need in the connection settings window. In "Connection" set `Address: localhost:27017`. Fill "Authentication" with the credentials to access your db. Fill "SSH" with the same parameters you use to access your server from the terminal. I use a private key from my .ssh folder. Let me know if you are stuck. Bonne chance!

Comment: Haaaaan that's how it's done? I had no idea the software could handle the SSH connection on its own. That's great, I have to try this.
PS: Robo3T is way better than Compass, changed my life already.
Cheers dude!

Comment: Yeah. Open software FTW! I'm glad I could help. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Ubuntu 20.04 and MongoDB server version 4.4.2...**

The issue for me ended up being that I was trying to use my machine's *public* IP address.

Once I specified my ***private*** IP address, everything started working.  The mongod service starts without any errors, and I am now able to connect to it from remote machines.

On Ubuntu, you can use the following command to get your private IP address:

```
hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'
```

Here's what I have in **/etc/mongod.conf** (only showing relevant sections, and partial private IP address):

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 172.##.##.##

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Note that putting brackets around the two IP addresses (as in the accepted answer) did NOT work for me, and resulted in a mongod status code of 2 (effectively a syntax error in the **mongod.conf** file).  Also the space after the comma seems to work now, though not required.

Comment: This fixed it for me on 18.04 as well

Answer (score -4):

I just reboot system (sudo reboot) it is working for me. i don't know why.