# Mongo-DB Error trying to access my remote db via public url

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have an issue with my mongodb on the remote server, when I bind my Ip to 127.0.0.1 mongod starts fine, but when a add my public IP to the bind mongod fail with the error message below, How can I solve this error?

> 2016-07-10T11:14:15.678+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {
>   config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1, XX.XXX.XX.XX",
>   port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: {
>   enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true,
>   path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } } 2016-07-10T11:14:15.710+0300 I
>   NETWORK  [initandlisten] getaddrinfo(" XX.XXX.XX.XX") failed: Name or
>   service not known 2016-07-10T11:14:15.710+0300 E NETWORK 
>   [initandlisten] listen(): socket is invalid.
>   2016-07-10T11:14:15.710+0300 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set
>   up sockets during startup. 2016-07-10T11:14:15.710+0300 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48

Comment: How are you connecting to the mongo db at amazon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongo-DB Error trying to access my remote db via public url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109134/how-to-set-mongod-conf-bind-ip-with-multiple-ip-address)

Comment: I figured out the error I had not exposed port 27017 on my remote server