# how to bind a specific ip to a mongodb service?

Tags: windows, mongodb, ip, config

I want to send a request to mongodb in a remote server machine.  The following line is in the configuration, and I am not allowed to remove it:

```
bindip:127.0.0.1
```

I want to bind the IP `45.56.65.100` to my mongodb service on Windows.

Can I include `45.56.65.100` in ip to solve the problem?

Comment: Restructured to make question more clear.  Added formatting, and updated title to remove extraneous information.

Comment: Hi athi_nn - what have you tried so far? For example, have you tried setting up an ssh tunnel to the remote server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set mongod.conf bind\_ip with multiple ip address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109134/how-to-set-mongod-conf-bind-ip-with-multiple-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind one IP as shown above "bindip:127.0.0.1"
All IPs for the machine using: "bindip:0.0.0.0"
Or multiple IPs as notated here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36450320/2585788

> bindIp: 172.31.60.184,127.0.0.1
>   Remember to not put a space after the comma.
>   answered Apr 6 at 11:50 Puneet Goyal

Please make sure to also up-vote the original related answer.

Comment: If you down-vote an answer, then you should always provide a comment as to why so the poster can work to improve that answer. Thank you!