# Connecting to mongodb sing C# quick tour not creating db or collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm going through the [mongoDB Driver Documentation Quick Tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/getting_started/quick_tour/) for the first time.  Specifically the 2.4 version.

I've created a fresh mongodb instance at the 192.168.1.50 address, and it appears to be running correctly.

The MongoDB documentation gives the following example:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.1.50:27017");
#It's ok if the database doesn't yet exist.  It will be created upon first use
var database = client.GetDatabase("testDB");
#It’s ok if the collection doesn’t yet exist. It will be created upon first use.
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("testCollection");
```

However, when I go on my server, and I enter the mongo console

```
mongo
```

And I list the databases using

```
show dbs
```

The output is only

```
admin 0.000GB
local 0.000GB
```

Is there anything else I should have done to make this work?  I'm getting no errors on try/catch, and it appears to be running fine.

---

**Troubleshooting**

So far I've confirmed that mongodb is running by using the following:

```
netstat -plntu
```

Shows mongod running on 27017 in the LISTEN state.

---

I'd also be interested in knowing if there's a way on the mongodb server to view live connections, so I could see if it were actually successfully connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that a method I had found on how to set multiple bindIp's was incorrect.  The problem wasn't with the C# at all.  I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109134/how-to-set-mongod-conf-bind-ip-with-multiple-ip-address)

In case that ever goes away, here's the current settings I had to follow for multiple ip's

edit file **/etc/mongod.conf**

Wrap the comma-separated-Ips with brackets

```
bindIp = [127.0.0.1, 192.168.184.155, 96.88.169.145]
```

My original code worked fine, I just didn't have the brackets on the bindIp.

Answer (score 3):

Well the problem is that you need to create almost one collection in order to persist the created database (weird right?) i tested it with robomongo and works in that way.

The problem is that `GetCollection` method is not creating the target collection, you can try with this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.1.50:27017");
        //# It's ok if the database doesn't yet exist.  It will be created upon first use
        var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
        //# It’s ok if the collection doesn’t yet exist. It will be created upon first use.

        string targetCollection = "testCollection";
        bool alreadyExists = database.ListCollections().ToList().Any(x => x.GetElement("name").Value.ToString() == targetCollection);

        if (!alreadyExists)
        {
            database.CreateCollection(targetCollection);
        }

        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(targetCollection);

    }
```

Comment: This also doesn't appear to work for me.  It hangs on the ```bool alreadyExists``` and never returns.

Comment: It turned out that my error was a configuration on the mongodb side.  My original code works, but so does yours.  Thanks for the help