# bind multiple IP in mongoDb 4.x.x

Tags: mongodb, configuration-files, mongodb4.0

for mongoDB 4.0.3,
unable to add multiple ips in bindIp

following config works for localhost

```
net:
   port:27017
   bindIp:127.0.0.1
```

Following works for logging from other ip:

```
net:
       port:27017
       bindIp:0.0.0.0
```

following doesn't work

```
   bindIp:127.0.0.1 10.0.0.10
   bindIp:127.0.0.1,10.0.0.10
   bindIp:"127.0.0.1,10.0.0.10"
   bindIp:"127.0.0.1 10.0.0.10"
   bindIp:[127.0.0.1,10.0.0.10]
   bindIp:[127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.10]
```

any ip other than 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 gives error for bindIP

If I try following:

```
bindIp:10.0.0.10
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 48
```

this [MongoDB Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) doesnt help

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No. I had to revert to MongoDB 3.4 as it was time sensitive.

Comment: I am researching this more than 4 hours now. Still can't find a solution !

Comment: Consider the following answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67605000/3665178

Answer (score 8):

Use ; I used in Mongo 4.2.2 version

```
 net:
   port: 27017
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1;10.0.1.149
```

Comment: Awesome!Using Mongodb version 4.4.4. Only this solution worked for me.

Comment: I tried this for 4.4.6, I am able to restart the server without any problem -until here seems fine your answer, but is impossible do the connection through the `mongo` command even from the server itself - do the following - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67605049/3665178

Comment: If I am correct your query are 1.After restart you could not access Mongo : Please check Public IP, may be it change.
2. how to access mongo from server terminal: sudo mongo --host localhost --username EXISTINGUSERNAME --password  EXISTINGPASSWORD --authenticationDatabase admin

Answer (score 7):

The documentation you linked actually does have the answer to this. If you go [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp), you will see that the indicate:

> To bind to multiple addresses, enter a list of comma-separated values.
>
> > EXAMPLE
> >
> > localhost,/tmp/mongod.sock

I applied this in my environment and can see that mongod is listening on local and the designated IP.

```
root@aqi-backup:~# netstat -pano | grep 27017
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.149:27017        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12541/mongod         off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12541/mongod         off (0.00/0/0)
```

Here is my mongod.conf file (relevant section).

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.0.1.149
```

Comment: One thing I did find is that you can't bind to an IP that isn't bound to an interface. The mongod service simply won't start if you typo the IP.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I found was open for all on MongoDB and control IPs t by firewall to specifics ips.
net:
port:27017
bindIp:0.0.0.0

Comment: That just opens up traffic acceptance from all incoming IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is The Simplest Configuration of BindIp Value for MongoDB above 4.X version mentioned by subhash sautiyal

1. vim /etc/mongod.conf
2. bindIp: 127.0.0.1;182.58.65.45;165.165.66.8
3. sudo service mongod restart

Comment: Do those IPs map back to something the person asking the question is using? Is that always the location of the config file?