# why we cannot add 2 bind_ip's in community edition of mongodb 6.0.6 version

Tags: mongodb

when I added 2 IPs in bing_ip on the MongoDB configuration file(ubuntu), I tried restarting of mongoDB service but it didn't allow and it asked me for systemctl daemon-reload. after doing the daemon reload. My MongoDB service vanished, and I started getting the error service not found. I am new in MongoDB can anyone explain to me what exactly happened

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109134/how-to-set-mongod-conf-bind-ip-with-multiple-ip-address

Comment: Why do you want to set 2 IP's? I don't know any reason where it would make sense.